# How to manage side-effecting commands when using reactive extensions?

Tags: wpf, f#, system.reactive

```ml
module CounterApp

open System
open System.Windows
open System.Windows.Controls
open System.Windows.Media

open System.Reactive.Linq
open System.Reactive.Disposables
open FSharp.Control.Reactive

/// Subscribers
let do' f c = f c; Disposable.Empty
let prop s v c = Observable.subscribe (s c) v
let event s f c = (s c : IEvent<_,_>).Subscribe(fun v -> f c v)
let children clear add set (v1 : IObservable<IObservable<IObservable<_>>>) c = // Note: The previous versions of this have bugs.
    let v2_disp = new SerialDisposable()
    new CompositeDisposable(
        v1.Subscribe(fun v2 ->
            clear c
            v2_disp.Disposable <- 
                let v3_disp = new CompositeDisposable()
                let mutable i = 0
                new CompositeDisposable(
                    v2.Subscribe (fun v3 ->
                        let i' = i
                        v3_disp.Add <| v3.Subscribe (fun v -> if i' < i then set c i' v else i <- add c v + 1)
                        ),
                    v3_disp
                    )
            ),
        v2_disp
        )
    :> IDisposable
let ui_element_collection v1 c = children (fun (c : UIElementCollection) -> c.Clear()) (fun c -> c.Add) (fun c i v -> c.RemoveAt i; c.Insert(i,v)) v1 c

/// Transformers
let control'<'a when 'a :> UIElement> (c : unit -> 'a) l = 
    Observable.Create (fun (sub : IObserver<_>) ->
        let c = c()
        let d = new CompositeDisposable()
        List.iter (fun x -> d.Add(x c)) l
        sub.OnNext(c)
        d :> IDisposable
        )
let control c l = control' c l :?> IObservable<UIElement>

let stack_panel' props childs = control StackPanel (List.append props [fun c -> ui_element_collection childs c.Children])
let stack_panel props childs = stack_panel' props (Observable.ofSeq childs |> Observable.single)
let window props content = control' Window (List.append props [prop (fun t v -> t.Content <- v) content])

/// The example
type Model = {
    Count : int
    Step : int
    TimerOn : bool
    }

type Msg =
    | Increment
    | Decrement
    | Reset
    | SetStep of int
    | TimerToggled of bool
    | TimedTick

let init = { Count = 0; Step = 1; TimerOn=false }

let pump = Subject.broadcast
let dispatch msg = pump.OnNext msg
let update =
    pump
    |> Observable.scanInit init (fun model msg ->
        match msg with
        | Increment -> { model with Count = model.Count + model.Step }
        | Decrement -> { model with Count = model.Count - model.Step }
        | Reset -> init
        | SetStep n -> { model with Step = n }
        | TimerToggled on -> { model with TimerOn = on }
        | TimedTick -> if model.TimerOn then { model with Count = model.Count + model.Step } else model 
        )
    |> Observable.startWith [init]

let timerCmd() =
    update
    |> Observable.map (fun x -> x.TimerOn)
    |> Observable.distinctUntilChanged
    |> Observable.combineLatest (Observable.interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0)))
    |> Observable.subscribe (fun (_,timerOn) -> 
        if timerOn then Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(fun () -> dispatch TimedTick)
        )

let view =
    window [ do' (fun t -> t.Title <- "Counter App")]
    <| control Border [
        do' (fun b -> b.Padding <- Thickness 30.0; b.BorderBrush <- Brushes.Black; b.Background <- Brushes.AliceBlue)
        prop (fun b v -> b.Child <- v) <|
            stack_panel [ do' (fun p -> p.VerticalAlignment <- VerticalAlignment.Center)] [
                control Label [
                    do' (fun l -> l.HorizontalAlignment <- HorizontalAlignment.Center; l.HorizontalContentAlignment <- HorizontalAlignment.Center; l.Width <- 50.0)
                    prop (fun l v -> l.Content <- v) (update |> Observable.map (fun model -> sprintf "%d" model.Count))
                    ]
                control Button [
                    do' (fun b -> b.Content <- "Increment"; b.HorizontalAlignment <- HorizontalAlignment.Center)
                    event (fun b -> b.Click) (fun b arg -> dispatch Increment)
                    ]
                control Button [
                    do' (fun b -> b.Content <- "Decrement"; b.HorizontalAlignment <- HorizontalAlignment.Center)
                    event (fun b -> b.Click) (fun b arg -> dispatch Decrement)
                    ]
                control Border [
                    do' (fun b -> b.Padding <- Thickness 20.0)
                    prop (fun b v -> b.Child <- v) <|
                        stack_panel [do' (fun p -> p.Orientation <- Orientation.Horizontal; p.HorizontalAlignment <- HorizontalAlignment.Center)] [
                            control Label [do' (fun l -> l.Content <- "Timer")]
                            control CheckBox [
                                prop (fun c v -> c.IsChecked <- Nullable(v)) (update |> Observable.map (fun model -> model.TimerOn))
                                event (fun c -> c.Checked) (fun c v -> dispatch (TimerToggled true))
                                event (fun c -> c.Unchecked) (fun c v -> dispatch (TimerToggled false))
                                ]
                            ]
                    ]
                control Slider [
                    do' (fun s -> s.Minimum <- 0.0; s.Maximum <- 10.0; s.IsSnapToTickEnabled <- true)
                    prop (fun s v -> s.Value <- v) (update |> Observable.map (fun model -> model.Step |> float))
                    event (fun s -> s.ValueChanged) (fun c v -> dispatch (SetStep (int v.NewValue)))
                    ]
                control Label [
                    do' (fun l -> l.HorizontalAlignment <- HorizontalAlignment.Center)
                    prop (fun l v -> l.Content <- v) (update |> Observable.map (fun model -> sprintf "Step size: %d" model.Step))
                    ]
                control Button [
                    do' (fun b -> b.HorizontalAlignment <- HorizontalAlignment.Center; b.Content <- "Reset")
                    prop (fun b v -> b.IsEnabled <- v) (update |> Observable.map (fun model -> model <> init))
                    event (fun b -> b.Click) (fun b v -> dispatch Reset)
                    ]
                ]
        ]

[<STAThread>]
[<EntryPoint>]
let main _ = 
    let a = Application()
    use __ = view.Subscribe (fun w -> a.MainWindow <- w; w.Show())
    use __ = timerCmd()
    a.Run()
```

I am translating the [Fabulous counter example](https://github.com/fsprojects/Fabulous/blob/master/Fabulous.XamarinForms/samples/CounterApp/CounterApp/CounterApp.fs) to [reactive extensions](https://github.com/mrakgr/Lithe-POC/blob/83ee40f5bd1ee5294f0733b9c526fc842d37e228/Lithe/05_CounterApp/CounterApp.fs). The above works, but I am not completely satisfied with how the command aspect came out.

```
let timerCmd() =
    update
    |> Observable.map (fun x -> x.TimerOn)
    |> Observable.distinctUntilChanged
    |> Observable.combineLatest (Observable.interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0)))
    |> Observable.subscribe (fun (_,timerOn) -> 
        if timerOn then Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(fun () -> dispatch TimedTick)
        )
```

This is how the timer command is defined as a function.

```
use __ = timerCmd()
```

I subscribe to it in the `main` function.

This is not quite expressing what I want.

For one, I do not want this to be a separate subscription in `main`. I do not want the `interval` observable to be turned on all the time in the background, only sending messages when allowed.

I want `timerCmd` to switch on automatically, subscribe to the interval and dispatch `TimedTick` messages - and switch off and unsubscribe based on the state of `x.TimerOn`. What would the best way to do this be? Is there a better way to design all of this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to shunt an interval timer in and out of the stream.
We can project onto an observable of either empty notifications or an interval, and then `switch` to the newest emitted observable.

```
let model = { Count = 0; Step = 0; TimerOn = false }
let update = Subject.behavior model

update
|> Observable.distinctUntilChangedKey (fun x -> x.TimerOn)
|> Observable.map (fun x -> 
    if x.TimerOn then 
        Observable.interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0)) 
    else 
        Observable.empty
)
|> Observable.switch
|> Observable.subscribe (fun i -> printfn "Tick %d" i)
|> ignore

while true do
    printfn "Start (y)?"
    let switch = Console.ReadLine()
    update 
    |> Subject.onNext( { model with TimerOn = switch = "y" })
    |> ignore
```

Output

```
Start (y)?
y
Start (y)?
Tick 0
Tick 1
Tick 2
Tick 3
n
Start (y)?
y
Start (y)?
Tick 0
Tick 1
```

As you can see the timer does restart when you want it to.

Comment: Interesting. I read about `Switch` in a book, but I thought it only selected the latest out of two observables. This one is much more useful. `distinctUntilChangedKey` is something I should be using too. I thought that `switchMap` would also work here, but that does not seem to be the case. I'll have to open an issue on the F# repo for that. This solves half my problems. The other is the design consideration for commands. I wonder if there is a good way to make it a part of the update `pipeline`?

Comment: I need something like `iter` that acts on the model like the identity function and just passes it along, but stateful like `scan` internally. There shouldn't be a need to really subscribe to `timerCmd` separately in `main`.

Comment: It would not be too hard to implement something like this, but I am not sure whether I should. Maybe having the command handlers be a part of a separate pipeline from the update-view one like I have now is in fact the ideal design. The design of reactive extensions is just the right amount of functional and imperative. Having combinators with complex internal state would go against that.

Comment: Interesting. It seems they implemented `switchMap` on their own, and it's not a very correct implementation at that.

Comment: Ideally the whole UI can be declaratively modeled as a series of reactive combinators describing behavior and action. And this  is fairly successful in ReactiveUI. But there are always edge cases. Choose the approach you think might lead to a lower number of corner cases. Personally I find a single-state application with a series of reducers impractical to scale up.

Comment: If it was written in a functional language, MVVM would be this except with a message pump for every single variable. That is no good either. At any rate, I've settled on the kind of design that I want [here](https://github.com/mrakgr/Lithe-POC/blob/9f5e82335209bb456a4ab65c0099402e626882e2/Lithe/05_CounterApp/Try1.fs). And [here is](https://github.com/mrakgr/Lithe-POC/blob/9f5e82335209bb456a4ab65c0099402e626882e2/Lithe/05_CounterApp/Try2.fs) a direct translation of the Fabulous Counter App. Thank you for the help.